# How to store last visited Product pages in cookie in PHP

Tags: php, session-cookies

```
// define the new value to add to the cookie
$ad_name = $myProductId; //comes from $_GET[]

// if the cookie exists, read it and unserialize it. If not, create a blank array
if(array_key_exists('recentviews', $_COOKIE)) {
    $cookie = $_COOKIE['recentviews'];
    $cookie = unserialize($cookie);
} else {
    $cookie = array();
}

// add the value to the array and serialize
$cookie[] = $ad_name;
$cookieString = serialize($cookie); /* changed $cookie to $cookieString */

// save the cookie
setcookie('recentviews', $cookieString , time()+3600); /* insert $cookiestring */

//prints to screen noting
foreach ($cookie as $h) { /* changed $_COOKIE['recentviews'] to $cookie */
        echo $h."-";

    }
```

This code does not work when clicked to view another product or url navigation, the old cookie value has been replaced by a new one. I want to save the old value and check if the duplicate will not be saved

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: Heads up, read the big red box on this page http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: You can use server based session cookies   http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php